# How to create a List which contains a type of interface, to only add class types which inerhit this interface?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create a collection of class types, I only want the types, not the objects - they all inerhit

```
IBuilderType
```

so how to write the list ->

```
public List<typeof(IBuilderType)> Builder;
```

to achieve this :

```
var listBuilder = new List<typeof(IBuilderType)> 
        {typeof (BasicCategoryBuilder)};
```

i want basicly a restriction to what types you can add to this list (range of classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Type` isn't generic, so you cannot check at compile time that the elements of `` List`1 `` are types of `IBuilderType`. You may want to check the type hierarchy by code and encapsule the list with some methods, but there's no way to constraint `Type` in generics.

```
var listBuilder = new List<Type/* : IBuilderType*/>() {
    typeof(BasicCategoryBuilder)
};
```

Comment: yeah i used now a normal list of types and added a check method for IBuilderType - thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a List with the generic type "System.Type" like this:

```
List<System.Type> myList = new List<System.Type>();
```

then you can add the types like this:

```
myList.Add(typeof(Bar));
myList.Add(typeof(Foo));
```